# failed to load data item: { "message": "The provided key element does not match the schema", "code":

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, alexa-skills-kit

Im trying to create a skill to pull data from my dynamoDB table and feed it back to me through alexa.

I want to be able to ask Alexa about a certain date and recall the information from this date.

im currently getting the following error with the code I currently have

```
failed to load data item: { "message": "The provided key element does not match the schema", "code":
```

Here is my current code:

```js
var AWSregion = 'us-east-1';  // us-east-1
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var dbClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
AWS.config.update({
    region: "'us-east-1'"
});

let handleCinemaIntent = (context, callback) => {    
  let params = {
    TableName: "cinema",
    Key: {
        date: "20180102",
        message: "Inception",
        time: "14:00"
    }
  };
  dbClient.get(params, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
       // failed to read from table for some reason..
       console.log('failed to load data item:\n' + JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
       // let skill tell the user that it couldn't find the data 
       sendResponse(context, callback, {
          output: "the data could not be loaded from your database",
          endSession: true
       });
    } else {
       console.log('loaded data item:\n' + JSON.stringify(data.Item, null, 2));
       // assuming the item has an attribute called "message"..
       sendResponse(context, callback, {
          output: data.Item.message,
          endSession: true
       });
    }
  });
};


function sendResponse(context, callback, responseOptions) {
  if(typeof callback === 'undefined') {
    context.succeed(buildResponse(responseOptions));
  } else {
    callback(null, buildResponse(responseOptions));
  }
}

function buildResponse(options) {
  var alexaResponse = {
    version: "1.0",
    response: {
      outputSpeech: {
        "type": "SSML",
        "ssml": `<speak><prosody rate="slow">${options.output}</prosody></speak>`
      },
      shouldEndSession: options.endSession
    }
  };
  if (options.repromptText) {
    alexaResponse.response.reprompt = {
      outputSpeech: {
        "type": "SSML",
        "ssml": `<speak><prosody rate="slow">${options.reprompt}</prosody></speak>`
      }
    };
  }
  return alexaResponse;
}

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  try {
    var request = event.request;
    if (request.type === "LaunchRequest") {
      sendResponse(context, callback, {
        output: "welcome to my skill. what do you want to find?",
        endSession: false
      });
    }
    else if (request.type === "IntentRequest") {
      let options = {};         
      if (request.intent.name === "cinema") {
        handleCinemaIntent(context, callback);
      } else if (request.intent.name === "AMAZON.StopIntent" || request.intent.name === "AMAZON.CancelIntent") {
        sendResponse(context, callback, {
          output: "ok. good bye!",
          endSession: true
        });
      }
      else if (request.intent.name === "AMAZON.HelpIntent") {
        sendResponse(context, callback, {
          output: "you can ask me about films",
          reprompt: "what can I help you with?",
          endSession: false
        });
      }
      else {
        sendResponse(context, callback, {
          output: "I don't know that one! Good bye!",
          endSession: true
        });
      }
    }
    else if (request.type === "SessionEndedRequest") {
      sendResponse(context, callback, ""); // no response needed
    }
    else {
      // un unexpected request type received.. just say I don't know..
      sendResponse(context, callback, {
          output: "I don't know that one! Good bye!",
          endSession: true
      });
    }
  } catch (e) {
    // handle the error by logging it and sending back an failure
    console.log('Unexpected error occurred in the skill handler!', e);
    if(typeof callback === 'undefined') {
       context.fail("Unexpected error");
    } else {
       callback("Unexpected error");
    }
  }
};
```

If it helps my table in dyanamodb has the columns
Date  |  Message  |  Time

I can also post my intent schema if required

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A DynamoDB table cannot have a primary key of 3 attributes (as your code suggests; date, message and time). It can either have a partition key or a partition key + sort key as its primary key.

Comment: Thank you, would i need to define everything in my first column? as currently its only giving the message in the partition key ive defined.

Comment: @zuba It depends on what attribute(s) uniquely identifies each item in the table, so that no two items can have the same key. You can read more about DynamoDB's primary key selection [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.CoreComponents.html#HowItWorks.CoreComponents.PrimaryKey).

Comment: thank you, do you know how i can change my skill to use a scan function instead as i intend to use date as my primary key and this will not be unique

Comment: @zuba If two items can have the same `date` value then you cannot use it as primary key. In all cases, you'll have to pick another attribute (sort key) that makes the primary key (partition + sort key) unique. Then, based on what attributes you've got, you can decide whether to use `get`, `query` or `scan`. Keep in mind that you can always use [secondary indexes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html) to query/scan the table if you don't have enough info to identify a primary key.

Comment: thanks for that, would you be able to help me in implementing a secondary index into the code i already have?